# Converting a string from utf8 to latin1 in NodeJS

Tags: node.js, encoding, utf-8, latin1

I'm using a Latin1 encoded DB and can't change it to UTF-8 meaning that I run into issues with certain application data. I'm using Tesseract to OCR a document (tesseract encodes in UTF-8) and tried to use iconv-lite; however, it creates a buffer and to convert that buffer into a string. But again, buffer to string conversion does not allow "latin1" encoding.

I've read a bunch of questions/answers; however, all I get is setting client encoding and stuff like that.

Any ideas?

Comment: Man...thanks. Idk how I missed that.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since Node.js v7.1.0, you can use the `transcode` function from the `buffer` module:
https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#buffer_buffer_transcode_source_fromenc_toenc

For example:

```js
const buffer = require('buffer');
const latin1Buffer = buffer.transcode(Buffer.from(utf8String), "utf8", "latin1");
const latin1String = latin1Buffer.toString("latin1");
```

Answer (score 3):

You can create a buffer from the UFT8 string you have, and then decode that buffer to Latin 1 using iconv-lite, like this

```
var buff   = new Buffer(tesseract_string, 'utf8');
var DB_str = iconv.decode(buff, 'ISO-8859-1');
```

Answer (score 1):

I've found a way to convert any encoded text file, to UTF8

```js
var 
  fs = require('fs'),
  charsetDetector = require('node-icu-charset-detector'),
  iconvlite = require('iconv-lite');

/* Having different encodings
 * on text files in a git repo
 * but need to serve always on 
 * standard 'utf-8'
 */
function getFileContentsInUTF8(file_path) {
  var content = fs.readFileSync(file_path);
  var original_charset = charsetDetector.detectCharset(content);
  var jsString = iconvlite.decode(content, original_charset.toString());
  return jsString;
}
```

I'ts also in a gist here: https://gist.github.com/jacargentina/be454c13fa19003cf9f48175e82304d5

Maybe you can try this, where `content` should be your *database buffer data* (in latin1 encoding)